# JUnit Test with InjectionPoint for @Produce on method for custom qualifier

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit

I've created a custom qualifier and created a class with a method to produce the value for it

```
public class ValueProducer {
    @Produces
    @ConfigurationValue
    public String getStringConfigValue(InjectionPoint ip) {
      ...
    }
}
```

`@ConfigurationValue` is my own created qualifier. Everything works fine when using it, so no problem on this site.

But I don't know how to emulate the InjectionPoint to create proper unit tests. The interface has a lot of methods to fill when creating an implementing class. Is there a simple way to create such an object without implementing the interface on my own? I also haven't found any example how anybody is testing these kind of methods.

Comment: If you need no function in it then you can just mock it (e.g. with Mockito) - if need need partial function you can use Mockito - spy . Or you could implement a dummy class as an anonymous inner type in the test if you do not want to use a mocking framework. Viel Spaß Herr Auskennfuchs :D

Comment: That's the exactly the problem. I need `.getMember()` and `.getAnnotated()` and these are really hard to Mock and require a lot of bloating code just to create an instance of these interfaces. That's why I'm curious if there is any easy method to synthetically create an InjectionPoint instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not bother with mocking and just write some kind of CDI integration tests. Here is an example using [CDI-Unit](http://bryncooke.github.io/cdi-unit/) (You could also use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) or [DeltaSpike test module](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/test-control.html) for this):

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses({ValueProducerTest.ValueProducer.class})
public class ValueProducerTest {

    @Inject
    @ConfigurationValue
    private String testValue;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(testValue, "Test");
    }

    public static class ValueProducer {
        @Produces
        @ConfigurationValue
        public String getStringConfigValue(InjectionPoint ip) {
            return "Test";
        }
    }

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
    public static @interface ConfigurationValue {}
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working but I've got some problems with injection of an EJB at the producer. So I've used normal mocking of the interface functions.

Comment: Probably this additional EJB is not visible by CDI-Unit, try adding it to @AdditionalClasses annotation.